# Creating Own Annotations in android for Sake of ORM for android

Tags: android, orm, annotations

I want to create a mini `ORM(Object Relational Mapping)` for android if some one of you have used Hibernate which is also an ORM but not for mobile in which you can create Class to Table mapping by using annotations.
What i want to create my annotations in android and than read that class by reflection and create tables.

in standard java i am able to create my annotations and use it. but for android i could not found any way to create annotations in android [This](http://androidannotations.org/) project using custom annotations but i could not found how.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
```

These above `Meta-Annotations` are available in standard java but not in android which help to create annotations

any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that these annotations are not available in Android?  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is a Java ORM for Android that uses annotations without problem:

```
@Target(value = FIELD)
@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
public @interface DatabaseField {
    ...
}
```

I also use `METHOD` retention elsewhere.  Here's the [source code for @DatabaseField](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormlite-core/trunk/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.java?view=markup) that compiles fine under all Android versions that I've tried (1.6 up through 3.0).

One thing to remember about annotations with Android is that their performance is terrible.  See:

> [Why are annotations under Android such a performance issue (slow)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417426/why-are-annotations-under-android-such-a-performance-issue-slow)

Comment: I was tried to use it but i think due to any reason it didn't work. and after reading your point that annotations cause performance issue. now thinking to leave it :(

Comment: Make sure to check out ORMLite @Cheeta.  It sounds like you were trying to do what it does.  You can also configure classes with config files to bypass the annotation startup issues.  http://ormlite.com/