# ORMlite, faster if I *REMOVE* annotations?

Tags: java, android, reflection, annotations, ormlite

in ormlite the annotations `@DatabaseField` are used to help create the database schema configuration file, and it then uses the configuration file for referencing variables in model objects, if I understand correctly.

The Ormlite documentation says this is used as an alternative for annotations because the java reflections api takes a lot of resources and causes a lot of garbage collection, which is true. Does this mean that I can remove all of my `@DatabaseField` lines and it will perform better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Ormlite documentation says this is used as an alternative for annotations because the java reflections api takes a lot of resources and causes a lot of garbage collection, which is true.

It is indeed.  Here's my post on the subject: [Why are annotations under Android such a performance issue (slow)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417426/why-are-annotations-under-android-such-a-performance-issue-slow)

> Does this mean that I can remove all of my @DatabaseField lines and it will perform better?

No.  Once you have the configuration file, the @DatabaseField annotations should not be referenced at all.  Removing them will only make it harder to regenerate the config file when you change your schema.