# Can Java doc comment propagate to multiple elements, not only to first under it?

Tags: java, comments

I am adding new things to a class and I want to have a short info about that in comments. Like this:

```
/**
 *  Added in September, 2013
 *  ----more description---
 */
public String newA;
public int newB; 
public boolean newC
...etc
```

This way, a description is only available to `newA` object since its the first one under the doc comment.

Is there a way that I apply the same comment to all new attributes under the `newA`?

This only applies to attributes since I have no problem adding doc comments to classes and methods.

Comment: good question, but why would you do that? if they are the same you should use an array or something

Comment: They are not the same. They are strings, booleans and integers. Will make and edit. thanks

Comment: @sandalone: If they are of different data types, how would you apply same comment to them?

Comment: but then they will have different descriptions

Comment: @Ravinder Because I simply want to know which one were added in this months. I will need this info in the later phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really a must-be in your project you can use annotations.

```
/**
 *  Added in September, 2013
 *  ----more description---
 */
public @interface SampleAnnotation {

}

@SampleAnnotation
int i;

@SampleAnnotation
boolean b;

@SampleAnnotation
String s;
```

However you should read about annotations performance first.

If the variables are of the same type you can use standard element comment by placing them in the same line.

```
/**
 *  Added in September, 2013
 *  ----more description---
 */
int i, j;
```

Comment: *What* exactly should he read about 'annotations performance', and where?

Comment: Some benchmarks and use-cases. Especially that they are much slower on devices with Android < 4.0 - [benchmark](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/28/mythbuster-android-annotation-performance-unravelled/), so IMHO we should use it very carefully when targeting older devices.

Comment: Hm, aren't annotation issue already fixed? Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417426/why-are-annotations-under-android-such-a-performance-issue-slow

Comment: That link is about *frameworks that use annotation processing.* The question is about user-defined annotations for documentation purposes, which aren't processed at all. Your suggestion and link are therefore irrelevant.