# Is ormlite_config.txt still needed?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Somehow (I don't know how or why), an `ormlite_config.txt` was generated without one column. When I noticed it, I generated a new `ormlite_config.txt`. But when I turned my app on (with the new config file), there were no records.

Is `ormlite_config.txt` still needed? Was it needed for older Androids? I have another app with a lot of records and I don't want to lose them, but I want to write my app properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ormlite_config.txt` was needed for performance reasons because of bad annotation performance under older Android OS releases.  See this question here:

> [Why are annotations under Android such a performance issue (slow)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417426/why-are-annotations-under-android-such-a-performance-issue-slow)

If you are running on new operating systems and the performance of your application seems to be "good enough" without it, then the answer is no, it is not needed.

Comment: Which version do you consider as new enough for skipping ormlite_config.txt? Is it Android 4.0, 4.1, 4.4 or 5.0? Thanks